# User registration mail using any email id

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have a registration page on my site. The users who register in my site, I want to send them a verification mail. I am able to send ail using my gmail id. But when I use my site mail id say www.xyz.com then mail is not getting sent please suggest me how to get it done.

Comment: If your site is running on linux machines check if [send mail utility is running](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sendmai.htm)..But your question is still not clear.. Why are you sending mail to end users from your gmail id?

Comment: I don't want to send mail from from gmail id, I want to use my domain id info@xyz.com. I am using windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your mail server is running, and if it linux server then grep your email ID from logs what you found as below: Replace Your@emailid with your email ID.

For exim:

> grep YOUR@emailid /var/log/exim_mainlog

In Sendmail:

> grep your@emailID /var/log/maillog

Comment: I am using java in windows environment. I don't know how to send the verification mail from my domain id info@xyz.com to my users.

Answer (score 0):

If you can send mails using the G-mail, then there is no issue with your script. As you are having issue with your own mail server or mail address, Make sure that exim or any other mail server is running on the server.

Also the domain say xyz.com is pointing to the server if it is having a MX as local domain.

For checking A record dig +trace xyz.com .Make sure that A record is points to the server.

For checking MX record dig +trace xyz.com MX . Make sure that MX is like "0 or 10 xyz.com"

Instead if it is using remote MX then make sure that you are using mail server IP as the remote mail server in the script.

Try sending mails using webmail client and make sure that there are no current issues with the mail mail server. like poor reputation or else.

In case domain is having remote MX, make sure that the your server IP is not listed in the firewall block of remote server.